# Permission issues with cool-retro-term terminal emulator: can't use bash commands

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions

I just installed the latest stable version of my favorite terminal emulator, cool-retro-term, and, upon running it, I get this:

```
user@main:~$ cool-retro-term
Qt: Session management error: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to retrieve device information
libGL error: Version 4 or later of flush extension not found
libGL error: failed to load driver: i915
default KB_LAYOUT_DIR:  "/snap/cool-retro-term/32/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/QMLTermWidget/kb-layouts"
QObject::connect: No such slot Konsole::TerminalDisplay_QML_51::close()
loadAllColorSchemes
Session::run() - program: "/bin/bash"
Session::run() - arguments: ("")
started!
Both point size and pixel size set. Using pixel size.
```

The GUI works just fine, but whenever I try to run commands from within the terminal emulator, I get a "permission denied" message.

I thought running as superuser might solve the permissions problem, but instead, I get:

```
username@main:~$ sudo cool-retro-term
mkdir: cannot create directory '/run/user/0': Permission denied
No protocol specified
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :0
Aborted
```

I have to admit I'm stumped here.
Is there something obvious I'm overlooking?

Please let me know.
Thanks!

(P.S. I've tried sudo-apt-get-update, and I've tried installing through Ubuntu's software application. Both installs had the same issue.)

Comment: I would think this `Qt: Session management error: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported` is the issue!

Comment: The Ubuntu version will also be helpful!

Comment: How was it installed? A youtube video says it's from a PPA (noobslab?)

Comment: Is this error only when using `sudo`? What happens if you run `echo foo`? And what happens if you run `/bin/ls`? Run both without `sudo` please.